# Mount metal letters to a wall so that they are removable

Tags: walls, mounting, removal, adhesive, metal

I have to mount some metal letters to a concrete wall. Until now the plan was to ad pins to the letters and glue them into the wall. This would have required making some holes in the wall.

Now the idea has been raised to create a mounting that makes it possible to remove the letter from the wall if necessary. Is there a mounting that allows one to fix a pin with a screw to the wall or something similar?

Comment: Usual solution *is* to just patch the concrete after the signage has been removed -- or to attach the text to a plaque and find some way to hang it, support it, or otherwise mount it to something other than the wall.

Comment: now i thought about a metal angle which makes it possible to use a simple screw for the wall or the letter... maybe thats the idea.

Comment: could you mount a rail, and hang letters on that

Comment: What does "remove" mean here?  Do you mean remove permanently without leaving holes in the wall after you move elsewhere?  Do you mean remove temporarily to clean and/or re-paint the wall behind the letters?  Do you mean remove to be replaced next week by a different content?  In what kind of environmental situation?  Indoors? Up on a the side of a monument under heavy weather?  All of these variations would suggest rather different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at 3M command adhesive strips? They hold very well but are easily removable later on.

Comment: the letters are hanging outside. with the sun and the metal letters we will have really high temperatures at daylight even in winter and low temperatures at night. this was one of my first ideas too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having used this stuff for outdoor purposes, here in Florida, I can suggest that it would work as well or better in extreme conditions than my often recommended 3M command adhesive strips.
[Scotch Outdoor Mounting Tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z4BV)

[image]

I've used this material on the inside of a vehicle windshield to hold the dash cam mount, which virtually melted off when bonded with the factory adhesive. It eventually failed, but five years in the hot Florida sun through glass with interior temperatures approaching 150 deg F means it holds up quite well overall.

Removable in this product means careful use of a razor knife or similarly sharp edge to slice between the components, but it's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

Concrete has an alkaline ph so just go with a silicone that is acid free.  If you have problems finding these at big box you would try an auto parts store.